# Unloading a View on back of navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In **non-arc** usually i do

```
      [webView stopLoading];
```

on
          viewDidUnload

But now in **ARC** since the **viewDidUnload** method wont be called where can i stoploading the webview on moving back(**ViewController pushed by a NavigationController**).

I wanna do this since i have few issues with WebView loading

Comment: the deprecation of `viewDidUnLoad` is in iOS6, if have no relation with ARC, in some cases `viewDidDisappear:` or `viewWillDisappear:` can do the trick for you

Comment: thanks i used viewWillDisappear and it worked for me but i dont know i did not have any problem when working in non-arc

Comment: if you are using storyboards you can also implement a `dealloc` method, it is called when the view is dismissed, I don't know if in the case of xib files the behavior is the same, I can not tested right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` not being called has nothing to do with ARC. One is a deprecated method in a framework, the other a compiler feature. `viewDidUnload` was deprecated in iOS 6, because, frankly, it isn't really needed if everything is written correctly.

Implementing the `stopLoading` logic in `viewDidDisappear:` is not recommended, because if you push another view controller on top of the one with the web view, it will also make it stop loading. Instead, call `stopLoading` in the view controller's `dealloc` method. When the view controller is popped from the navigation stack, it is released and the `dealloc` method is called.

Comment: I am not using storyboards so i cant use dealloc if in case i am not pushing any controller on top can i use viewDidDisappear

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy `dealloc` has nothing to do with storyboards. When objects are released, their `dealloc` method is called.

Please read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming)

Comment: ARC is just compiler generated code to help you manage memory. Objects are still allocated, retained, released and deallocated; you just let the compiler do the heavy lifting for you. When you push a view controller in a navigation controller, it is retained. When you pop the view controller (go back), it is released. Since no other is retaining it, the `dealloc` method is called.

Comment: Thanks I have to say that today i have got something to learn more from your answer thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [webView stopLoading];
}
```

It will work fine, even if, you are using `ARC`.

However you can't call `[super dealloc];` in it. Because, that will be generated by compiler itself.